# Array showing series without duplicate and after last array begins from first in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using:

```
$input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
```

Now I want to start by printing the first value from the array (1) and another value for the remaining ones (2,3,4,5).  Then next time, the print value will be 2 and further values (3,4,5,1).  And so on, until the print value is 5 and the other values will be (1,2,3,4).

I am using a for-loop, but after the value 5, the loop should break...

What to do for this case....

out put should be: 1 the first time, then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5 then again 1 then continue  on every refresh

Comment: rather than explain with words, show the ouput you want. Thanks.

Comment: Or explain with words and the desired output. That way we can glean the best information possible.

Comment: Print first time 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5 then again 1then continue

Comment: "on every refresh" .. so is this data being stored in a session as well, or something? This question is very unclear and poorly demonstrated.

Comment: what a problem with question... i have a  array with 5 value and i want to show 1 value from array in increasing order and after last value loop start with first...

Comment: See my answer. If that's not what you want, I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you are looking for?

```
<?php

$input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
$arr = array();

foreach ($input as $item) {
    $i = array_shift($input);
    $arr[] = $input;
    $input[] = $i;
}

print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )
)
```

Comment: 1 value only and change after refresh... first time 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5 then again 1then continue on every refresh

Comment: @user1374160 : Use session variables

Comment: If by refresh you mean each time the loop starts over, then my answer should be pretty to the point. If you mean you want the user to refresh the page and get the next (or starting) number, that's a different strategy. If you mean you want it to go on forever and then pick up where it left off when the user refreshes page, then it's a gonna be a hybrid of the two.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['loop_num'])){
   $_SESSION['loop_num'] = 1;
}

$loop = true;

echo "Current: {$_SESSION['loop_num']} <br>";
$i = $_SESSION['loop_num'];

while($loop === true) {
    if($i >= 5){
        $i = 1;
    } else {
        $i++;
    }

    if($_SESSION['loop_num'] == $i){
        $loop = false;
        break;
    }
    $others[] = $i;

} 

if($_SESSION['loop_num'] >= 5){
        $_SESSION['loop_num'] = 1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['loop_num']++;
    }
print_r($others);
?>
```

Output:

```
Current: 4 
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 )

Current: 5 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )
```

etc..

Comment: yesi want this... thanks Blake.... can u tell me one more thing that without session this is possible or not....????

Comment: If you store it in a database or flat file, but that seems silly. (I'm presuming you won't want cookies either since you don't want sessions)

Comment: Upvotes are appreciated, and if an answer was provided, please mark it as such :)

Comment: but why u not use array i have value in array...  and pick 1 value same as ur output...

Comment: Not to be a hater, but I thought my answer was pretty slick, given that it can be any array. If I had known it was per page load, Ida beatcha to it.  But to answer the question on sessions, I totally agree with Blake. You can store the value anywhere, but sessions are designed for this and have no added overhead. Plus, if you did it in your own file, you'd have to keep track of which user was on which array value, etc.

Comment: @user1374160 - You are using the array (or you would be if you went with my session based solution), but the array can only persist between each refresh if it's stored somewhere, ideally in a session variable. Once you refresh, that array is gone unless you stashed it somewhere.

Comment: @Anthony Not to be a hater, but you didn't address the "other numbers in an array" aspect of the question. But I like where you were going with it. I wasn't going to overcomplicate my answer so he could understand / change it later (since it seems like he's somewhat new to PHP to me).

Comment: @Blake - I tend to go for clever over simple, it's true.  Which "other numbers in an array" aspect did I miss?  Maybe I missed more than I realized.

Comment: @Anthony OP said "Now I want to start by printing the first value from the array (1) and another value for the remaining ones (2,3,4,5)." So he wants current iteration, ie 3, with an array of the "other values" in this case, (4,5,1,2).

Comment: Thnanks to all for supporting and giving your important time for discussion... thanks to all... TC

Comment: @Blake -- So he wants the remaining in series (wherever in the loop they may be) as it's own array? I thought he was just making the point that this would be what would be next in line.  I could have tacked that on too! ah well.  +1 for reading and explaining well!

Comment: @Blake -- too litte too late, but take a look at my edited answer. Should work with any array so it could be neat for making a flip book.

Answer (score 0):

try implementing this solution:

```
$size = count($input);
$input = array_merge($input,$input);
for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
    $output = array_slice($input,$i,$size-1);
    print_r($output);
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types` Did you test your code?

Comment: array_slice expects first argument to be array. You passed in array+1, which doesn't work. Fixed it.

Comment: is it a practice to provide the complete code. isn't it understood that the $input variable is an array??

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a constantly rotating array that loops forever, this works:

```
$array = range(1,5);

foreach($array as &$number) {
    echo $number . PHP_EOL;
    array_push($array, array_shift($array));
}
```

If you want it to rotate per page load, setting the front number to one variable the rest in line in a dedicated array, this works:

```
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['loop_array']) {
    $_SESSION['loop_array'] = range(1,5);
} 
    $current_value = array_shift($_SESSION['loop_array']);
    $others_values = $_SESSION['loop_array'];

    // Push current value to back of rotation, leaving next in line for
    // next page load.
    array_push($current_value, $_SESSION['loop_array']);
```

This will also work with the following arrays (or any array):

```
$_SESSION['cute'] = array("dog", "cat", "pony", "bunny", "moose");

$_SESSION['ordinals'] = array("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth");

$_SESSION['tick_tock_clock'] = array("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", 
                                     "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X", "XI", "XII");

$_SESSION['randomness'] = array('butter', 'pillow', 'Alabama', 'bleeding gums');
```

Comment: @user1374160 - based on your original question, the browser is going to hang because it just keeps outputting the array in a loop forever. Read the updated answer that is per page load.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 

$input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");

while(!empty($input)) {

    foreach($input as $i) {

        var_dump($i);

    }

    $input = array_splice($input, 0, count($input) - 1);

}

?>
```

Comment: This just essentially counts down in reverse.. the OP clearly uses "5" again in his (albeit poorly posed) question.

Comment: wasn't this asked in question?